# Fsockopen not working when initiated by server on itself

Tags: php, yii, cgi, yii-extensions, fsockopen

I use a Yii extension called ERunActions to run background process such as sending mails to users. This extension internally uses fsockopen to accomplish this task. It all works fine in development but in server using fsockopen redirects me to http://example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

I read the documentation for fsockopen in php.net - https://www.php.net/function.fsockopen
and ran the following code in my dev environment (I replaced example.com with my site URL), everything works fine & the HTML content of my home page is shown, but when i run the same code in server I get redirected to the cgi URL. Any help will be greatly appreciated thank you.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

I found this in the access log

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 11:25:17 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 10:19:00 GMT ETag: "43bdf-6f-4e563e69a0d03" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 111 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about your production server? Especially web server type and configuration for the given web location would be helpful. Also have a look at the web server logs and see which events are logged inside your access logs, i.e. if you find any 301, 302 or 307s.

Comment: Production server is LAMP same as development, it is a VPS but don't know if that is relevant in this case, by 301, 302 do you mean HTTP Codes?

Comment: Exactly, have a look at your access.log and see what kind of HTTP status codes are logged around the time when you issued the fsockopen() call.